# If f(x, y) is convex, is g(x)=f(x, c) convex, for any constant c?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, convex-analysis

If $f(x, y)$ is convex (concave) defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $g(x)=f(x, c)$, $c\in \mathbb{R}$, then is $g(x)$ necessarily convex (concave)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Suppose $f(x,y)$ is convex. Let $t \in [0,1]$. For all $x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb R$,

\begin{align}g((1 - t)x_1 + tx_2) &= f((1 - t)x_1 + tx_2, c)\\
& = f((1 - t)x_1 + tx_2, (1 - t)c + tc)\\
& = f((1 - t)(x_1,c) + t(x_2,c))\\
& \le (1 - t)f(x_1,c) + tf(x_2,c)\\
& = (1 - t)g(x_1) + tg(x_2)
\end{align}

The second-to-last step follows from convexity of $f$. Thus $g$ is convex. Similarly, if $f$ is concave, then $g$ is concave.

Comment: Right! g((1-t)x1+tx2) is in fact equal to f((1-t)(x1, c)+t(x2,c)). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes !

Just write the definition of $f(x,y)$'s convexity and consider the special case where all points lie on the same line $(\cdot,c)$.